# Does ng-repeat retain DOM elements or create all new ones when the collection changes?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've seen a lot of questions about the order in which ng-repeat finishes compared to other directives or things going on in Angular land, but I haven't been able to find an answer to how exactly it accomplishes this.

I have two ideas of how it could work.

**First Way:** 
When ng-repeat's watcher triggers, it removes all elements it created from the DOM then creates all new elements in their place, even if many of those elements are the same (e.g. in the case of 1 item added to the backing array).

**Second way:** Since ng-repeat already keeps track of which elements go with which items in its backing collection, it simply removes the items that no longer exist in the collection and creates new elements for items that are new to the collection.

Which is it and why?

Comment: you might find some examples on the net where ng-repeat is combined with ng-animate like this: http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat/move . You'll see that new items are "animated into" the list and disappearing items "animated out of" the list. This wouldn't be possible if the DOM list was recreated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the **second way:** Angular [tries to be smart about creating/removing DOM elements](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2443-rendering-dom-elements-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs.htm):

> The `ngRepeat` directive provides a way to render a collection of items given a template. To do this, AngularJS compiles the given template and then clones it for each unique item in the collection. As the collection is mutated by the Controller, AngularJS adds, removes, and updates the relevant DOM elements as needed.
>
> But, how does AngularJS know which actions to perform when? If you start to test the rendering, you'll discover that AngularJS doesn't brute force DOM creation; that is, it doesn't recreate the DOM for every rendering. Instead, it only creates a new DOM element when a completely new item has been introduced to the collection. If an existing item has been updated, AngularJS merely updates the relevant DOM properties rather than creating a new DOM node.

This can still impact performance unnecessarily, i.e. when passing elements by-value in a collection (there's an excellent example of this in the blog post linked above). That's why [Angular supports "track by" for ngRepeat](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-using-track-by-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs-1-2.htm) since version 1.2: It's a way to help Angular decide when DOM creation is necessary:

> With this association in place, AngularJS will not $destroy and re-create DOM nodes unnecessarily. This can have a huge performance and user experience benefit.

The official documentation [states](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> You can also provide an optional tracking function which can be used to associate the objects in the collection with the DOM elements. If no tracking function is specified the ng-repeat associates elements by identity in the collection.
>
> For example: `item in items track by item.id` is a typical pattern when the items come from the database. In this case the object identity does not matter. Two objects are considered equivalent as long as their id property is same.