# Rebuild of DOM when collection of ng-repeat changes

Tags: angularjs

I've read in another stack overflow post that angular.js tries to be smart when the collection used in ng-repeat changes so that the DOM is not rebuilt completely (see [Does ng-repeat retain DOM elements or create all new ones when the collection changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766534/does-ng-repeat-retain-dom-elements-or-create-all-new-ones-when-the-collection-ch)). However I'm experiencing a problem: When I remove one item from my collection, all items following this one are rebuilt in the DOM. This is problematic for me because I am listing for the jQuery remove event and this event gets fired multiple times, although only one item got removed. Listening for `scope.$on('remove')` could solve my problem - this gets only triggered once - but here is my problem, that I want to access jQuery `data` before removing and when `scope.$on('remove')` is triggered, `data` got already removed.

What can I do to solve this issue? See this link for a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/T1ZicU20JjWYk1J5ch7Z?p=preview.

```
element.bind('remove', function() {
  alert("Element remove handler called.");
});
```

When I remove the third element, remove gets already triggered once, when I remove the second one, it gets triggered twice, when removing the third one, it gets triggered thrice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `track by` to solve this issue :
    `ng-repeat="w in widgets track by $index"`

Explanation:
When you add `track by` you basically tell angular to generate a single DOM element per data object in the given collection. This could be useful when paging and filtering, or any case where objects are added or removed from `ng-repeat` list.

Reference: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-using-track-by-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs-1-2.htm

Comment: Wow, this works. Could you explain why it works? What if I get the list of widgets from a database? Can I use `track by $index` in this case too or can this lead to problems?

Comment: @karot Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you. But why is this not working when I add a unique id to each widget and use `track by w.id`?

Comment: @karot You will have to define `id` property attached to the widgets object (inside your `addWidget` function) for `track by w.id` to work.

Comment: Yes, I have defined `id` in my initial list. See: http://plnkr.co/edit/RcnntTgyFyYTKOukgcbv?p=preview

Comment: @karot Not sure why it doesn't work. Will check it out and update keep you updated.